# "fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref" error when fetching git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

##### **Scenario**

I am trying to setup [`torch-mlir`](https://github.com/llvm/torch-mlir) repository on my personal server. This repository has two submodules, [`llvm-project`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project) and [`mlir-hlo`](https://github.com/tensorflow/mlir-hlo).

Now, on my server, I already have `llvm-project` and `mlir-hlo`. However, I am unable to replace the links for these submodules in the `torch-mlir` project.

---

##### **What I've tried**

1. Cloned `torch-mlir` locally
2. replaced the urls of the submodules in the `.gitmodule` file
3. used the command: `git submodule deinit`
4. went inside the `externals/llvm-project` and `externals/mlir-hlo` and executed the following commands respectively:

   1. `git remote set-url origin <my server path to llvm-project>`
   2. `git remote set-url origin <my server path to mlir-hlo>`
5. Back at project root, executed `git submodule sync`
6. now executed, `git submodule update --init --recursive`

I am receiving the following error:

```bash
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref <aHash>
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Fetched in submodule path 'externals/mlir-hlo', but it did not contain <aHash>. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

This commit hash does not even exist in the original github.com repo for mlir-hlo.

What is the correct way of replacing the submodules so that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following (resulted in a successful setup and build):

I moved under the `torch-mlir` directory and executed the following steps.

###### Step 1: Remove the existing submodules

Check the current status of sub-modules:

```bash
git submodule status
```

We wish to remove these, since they are linked to the **github.com** links:

```bash
git rm -r --cached externals/mlir-hlo
git rm -r --cached externals/llvm-project
rm -rf externals/llvm-project; rm -rf  externals/mlir-hlo;
```

This will remove the submodules and their cached indices.

###### Step 2: Add the local submodule config

First, update the link to submodule repositories:

```bash
nano .gitmodules
```

Now, ensure the links are thoroughly updated:

```bash
git submodule add --force <your server path to mlir-hlo>.git externals/mlir-hlo

git submodule add --force <your server path to llvm-project>.git externals/llvm-project
```

The above commands will download the repositories and place them in the submodule's respective path.

For each submodule, select the particular branch (on your server's repo):

```bash
git submodule set-branch --branch main externals/mlir-hlo
git submodule set-branch --branch release/16.x externals/llvm-project
```

Ensure all submodules are synced up:

```bash
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

After this, we can go ahead and build the `torch-mlir` project as per the documentation for that project.